# how to use zz mutually defined BIG07 - Liaison EDI notepad

Tags: biztalk, edi

note: I am using Liaison EDI notepad for syntax error checking.

For EDI processing there are a lot of places where you can use 'ZZ=mutually defined' as a value. For instance, I am working with creating an 810 4010 document, and for BIG07 (transaction type code) none of the codes that I can choose are the ones I want. I want my customers to use codes that I create. I want them to use the code 'HR' for human resource or 'SC' for supply chain. So can someone tell me how I can do this? And also what does 'ZZ=mutually defined' in Liaison EDI notepad mean?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you want and need to do this.  "Human Resource" and "Supply Chain" don't really sound like credible invoice types and you risk just annoying the trading partners with such a deviation.  There are several hundred valid codes already.

How exactly do you plan to use this?  Maybe there is a better way, like the NTE segment which kind of a catch-all already.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it. I want the customer to submit invoices to us. I have a few different types of invoices that they can send. I want a field to represent what type of invoice they're sending. I have a lot of other fields in other segments that are using ZZ because there just aren't the codes to define the type of data I need

Comment: Also, where can I go to learn more about this? finding any information on this is so incredibly difficult. It's really frustrating actually. It seems like everyone knows how this is supposed to work, but its a secret kidn of education

Comment: Nope, we just learn as we go most of the time.  You can get the exact definitions of the code lists but have to pay.  I've never needed to.  If there's really so many missing codes, maybe you're over-thinking it, just pick one that's close.

Comment: Picking one that is close is something I'll do. I can make that work. Any idea where I can put a line item comment?

Comment: PID or PWK might suit the requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I looked through those. I am deciding on using the REF field

Answer (score 1):

ZZ is not a Liaison specific qualifer.  ZZ means mutually defined per the ANSI X12 standard.  It's kind of a "catch all" where the trading partners can agree that ZZ will suit their needs because the other codes might not necessarily apply.   It's used a lot of times in the ISA where a trading partner will arbitrarily make up their identifier instead of using a phone number or DUNS number.

Besides Google, there are a few resources out there like give you a high level of how EDI works.  I'm assuming BizTalk doesn't provide you with a solid X12 dictionary viewer, so perhaps you might want to purchase the Dictionary Viewer from Liaison. You might want to check out [http://www.edibasics.com/](http://www.edibasics.com)

You need to check with your customers to see if they can even provide what you're looking for.  If not, you're just wasting your time.  If you're going to bastardize the standard (which is not uncommon) it doesn't mean your partner is going to jump through the hoops to give you what you want.  It might not be feasible on their end, and you could wind up irritating your customer.  Irritating a customer is never a good idea.  On their end, it is possible that an invoice is an invoice and they can't differentiate between the two.  Or, they might be able to differentiate by an invoice number prefix or suffix.  Then your mapping logic can use that.

Comment: Thank you for giving me something to look up. X12 dictionary. And also, the prefix on an invoice number is a genius idea. Thank you for that. And about seeing what my customer can provide, I guess its really important that I keep in touch with them on what I need on my invoice. This whole customer interaction part has been the biggest question mark for me.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation on the ZZ qualifer

Comment: A simpler thought based on an assumption: your invoice is based on a PO, right?  So you should know what kind of PO it is.  The invoice is going to have your PO number on it in the BIG segment, so just look up what type of PO it is.  Therefore, you don't need to put any headaches on your customer.